# Change the login screen theme in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, login, themes, gdm

Can anyone show me a way to change the default login screen theme with the ones available at http://www.gnome-look.org ?

For eg, this 
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/HexLogin?content=169840

I managed to download this as a .tar.gz file but how should I install it?
I have installed gdm and ubuntu tweak, but couldn't find a way to install it.

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate question, the solution given in the other questions aren't working for 14.04.

Comment: Nope, that question does not give an existing solution for ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried opening the tar file using `tar -xvf (name of the download)`
or `-tvzf` if you want to see the contents of the file before you open it?